# ruby / ability to share a single variable between multiple classes

Tags: ruby, class, variables, inheritance

For general classes manipulation understanding;
given the following use case :

```
class Child1
  def process var
    'child1' + var
  end
end

class Child2
  def process var
    'child1' + var
  end
end

class Child3
  def process var
    'child3' + var
  end
end

...

class Master
  attr_reader :var
  def initialize(var)
    @var = var
  end

  def process
    [
      Child1.new.process(var),
      Child2.new.process(var),
      Child3.new.process(var)
    ]
  end
end
```

by some kind of inheritance or structure, would there be a way to have `var` available to all children ?

Meaning :

```
class Child1 < Inherited
  def process
    'child1' + var
  end
end

...

class Master
  ...
  def process
    [
      Child1.new.process,
      ...
    ]
  end
end
```

I don't know my thing enough to find the preferred approached (eventhough the first example above do work ok, while not being the most elegant probably); thanks for any guidance

Comment: You don't want to pass information as a method argument (not even to the `new` method) but you want it visible anyway? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yep thats right. I'd say, to have it available to any potential descendents. Am getting a bit confused because here the initialize will be the same; while needed to be called once

Comment: "By some kind of inheritance or structure, would there be a way to have var available to all children?" For an instance of any class to acquire the value of `@var` for a particular instance of `Master` it would have to know that instance `m` (then `m.instance_variable_get(:@:var)`). Of course, if `Master` kept `m` in a class instance variable (`@m = m`) `Master` could be asked for that value (`Master.instance_variable_get(:@m)`). This 
 is not an inheritance issue, however, and strikes me as an odd and questionable design (assuming my understanding of the question is correct).

Comment: @CarySwoveland well, i might to have insisted enough, but i was indeed asking for a better design. A main class has to aggregate many other classes; this main class holds the variable that all other classes relies on. This is what is mistakenly called inheritance maybe, but i hope you get the idea

Comment: Can you simply make `@var` a class instance variable of `Master`? Then instances of children of `Master` can get its values by executing `self.class.superclass.instance_variable_get(:@var)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think that inheriting from `Master` class is OP's intention here, though I see your point, yet it would pollute children classes with unnecessary methods (like the `process` one). @Ben I think you're best off by just iterating through children properly, `[Child1, Child2, Child3].each { |c| c.new.process(var) }`, though it is not a direct answer to your question.

Comment: Should  the 9th line be `'child2' + var` ?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej thx and yes, this is actually what I ended up doing; in the question was my previous state. One thing, am a bit bothered that then in that case, it is possible to have the children inherit from the master `initialize` method; as it makes no sense to write it everywhere. I quite felt bad about such design, although it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 years later, ended up relying almost systematically to inheritance for such things, using simple def's, super sometimes, etc... all those are ruby classes native behaviours.

```
class Base
  private

  def class_variable
    0
  end
end

class B < Base
  def update
    # class_variable is made available by the Base inheritance
    class_variable + 1
  end
end

class C < B
  def update_from_base
    # class_variable is made available by A
    # B inherit from Base, so we do have class_variable available here
    # -> will output 2
    class_variable + 2
  end

 def update
    # as we inherit from B, and as B provides and update method
    # using super, we're then extending the def update available from B
    # -> will output 3 
    super + 2
  end
end
```

... and so on. It is a simple example; but scales well even for complex business logic, as it tends to help you focus on shared parts of your code base while you organize your classes hierarchically in terms of responsibilities.

Comment: Do note that you don't need inheritance for this approach to work. `Base`, `B`, and `C` might just as well be modules. You would then need to `include Base` or `include B` to make "parent" methods available.

Comment: Haven't said this was a requirement; the use you describe is way more usual indeed. That is, both are structure ruby provides. Relying on an inheritance tree of classes tends to scale better - but this is a totally personal opinion. would you recommend the `@@class_variable` approach answered first ?

Comment: That fully depends on the scenario. Class variables can lead to bugs, because people don't always expect that setting `@@something` in class `B` also changes the value in class `A`. The solution that you provide here is not really a variable, but essentially a method returning a static value.  Both have their advantages and downsides.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I see `include Base` as a different flavor of inheritance; does module provides anythings besides methods returning static values ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for class variables.

> ### [Class Variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Class+Variables)
>
> [Class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html) variables are shared between a class, its subclasses and its instances.
>
> A class variable must start with a `@@` (two “at” signs). The rest of the name follows the same rules as instance variables.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> class A
>   @@class_variable = 0
>
>   def value
>     @@class_variable
>   end
>
>   def update
>     @@class_variable = @@class_variable + 1
>   end
> end
>
> class B < A
>   def update
>     @@class_variable = @@class_variable + 2
>   end
> end
>
> a = A.new
> b = B.new
>
> puts "A value: #{a.value}"
> puts "B value: #{b.value}"
> ```
>
> This prints:
>
> ```
> A value: 0
> B value: 0
> ```
>
> Continuing with the same example, we can update using objects from either class and the value is shared:
>
> ```
> puts "update A"
> a.update
>
> puts "A value: #{a.value}"
> puts "B value: #{b.value}"
>
> puts "update B"
> b.update
>
> puts "A value: #{a.value}"
> puts "B value: #{b.value}"
>
> puts "update A"
> a.update
>
> puts "A value: #{a.value}"
> puts "B value: #{b.value}"
> ```
>
> This prints:
>
> ```
> update A
> A value: 1
> B value: 1
> update B
> A value: 3
> B value: 3
> update A
> A value: 4
> B value: 4
> ```
>
> Accessing an uninitialized class variable will raise a [NameError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/NameError.html) exception.
>
> Note that classes have instance variables because classes are objects, so try not to confuse class and instance variables.